# Apparent depth and virtual image position

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [bbci.co.uk](https://a.files.bbci.co.uk/bam/live/content/z8r34wx/small))</sub>

Why does the virtual image appear right on top of the object and not a little to the right, for example? Is it explained by some formula or just symmetry of the geometry?

Comment: Why should the image be '''a little to the right,'''?
what do you think?

Comment: Try writing the vector equations for the perceived ray angles (via Snell's law), keeping in mind that the full image depends on tracing light from several points on the fish's body.

Comment: @Paul, I can't think of an argument as to why "a little to the right". But I have never considered that case before and I have always accepted that it must be on top of the object.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thank you very much! Now I understand it.

Comment: Samuil, in that case, go ahead and post your own answer to this question, for the benefit of future readers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that, when looking at an object, in order to determine where it is, you need several rays coming at slightly different angles and from all over the object's surface. Using Snell's Law and tracing back the rays to the point where they converge you get the full image and its apparent position. The next image represents this idea:

[image: rays converging]

Comment: Slightly pedantic point: you need to use a narrow bundle of rays (*i.e.* make a paraxial approximation) as the rays in the air don't quite converge to a point: you get spherical aberration.