# Apparent depth WITH viewing angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, refraction

So i did one physics problem where I should find apparent depth of 3m deep pool(index between liquid in pool and air is (√7)/2) and we are looking at pool from 30° angle.

I go to our favorite friend Google for help. I find some equation similar to (real depth)/(apparent depth)=refractive index. This doesn't work.

I got ~2.4m using this and I think Sneil law, but right answer is that ~2.1m is apparent depth.

Why doesn't this equation work? I think it doesn't work bc there is not angle in this equation, but how do I use it?

IMPORTANT: Pls use simple language and simple explanations bc I am not that smart when i comes to physics. I know basics of optics and light etc and this question is real mindfuck for me. I have seen 1 explanation which I don't understand, so keep that in mind please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) The principle is to consider two rays leaving a point at the bottom of the pool at small angles to each other, and therefore refract into the air at small angles to each other. One might emerge at 30° to the normal, the other at 31°. Suppose that these rays enter your eye. Draw these rays as dotted lines backwards through the water *as if they didn't refract* and where they meet will be the *apparent position* of the point on the bottom of the pool.

(b) You could do this by (big) scale diagram, only you'll need a wider difference between emergent angles. Maybe take one as 27° to the normal, the other as 33°. Use Snell's law to get the angles to the normal in the water.

(c) It is possible to do this mathematically and come up with a formula but it's not particularly easy to do. In fact I needed to use a little differential calculus. I can't believe that you are supposed to do the problem this way if you are not a university level student.

For what it's worth I obtained
$$\frac{h_r}{h_a}=n\frac{\cos^3 w}{\cos^3 a}$$
Here $h_r$ and $h_a$ are the real and apparent (vertical) depths. $a$ and $w$ are the angles to the normal of the ray in air and water respectively. These angles are, of course, related by
$$\sin a = n \sin w.$$

This gives me an apparent depth of 1.86 m, for a real depth of 3.00 m and a 30° viewing angle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it and I am thankful for it. The problem is that the apparent depth is ~2.1m. This is the hardest question on the test that ranks you for uni(I am taking the test for uni soon if you need that info). I was trying to understand it so I can get to uni. With sneil law it got 2.4m which is one of the answers you are given to choose from(I would be wrong if I choose 2.4m instead of 2.1m). Your answer is also there(again wrong, I am sorry about that), if I choose it I would be wrong and I would get negative points.

Comment: @Jon Nezbit (a) Just to check my interpretation of the fraction given for $n$: $n=1.322$. Agreed? (b) If you use the standard (vertical viewing) formula, as given by Ohw, you get an apparent depth of 2.27 m. I Don't know what you mean when you say "*with Snell's law* [I] got 2.4 m". (c) I assume that the depths are measured vertically.

Comment: All of your assumptions are true n is about 1.3228..., with vertical viewing I got almost 2.4m(probably a little bit off because of the way I rounded variables), word "depth" means it is measured vertically if I am right . I used it like Ohm said(the equation for small angles).

Comment: I can send you(or upload to imgur or something) the whole physics problem if it adds to discussion and if I helps with the current topic. I am not lookin

Comment: That would be interesting, but don't go to too much trouble. I think you might try the scale drawing; it would give you insight. As for rounding, I hope you keep everything in your calculator as far as is possible. University of Prague?

Comment: Here is the whole physics problem word for word: Depth of the pool is 3 meters. If you fill it to the top with the water ( refraction index is n=(√7)/2 ) and view it from 30 degree angle from the line perpendicular to water, apparent depth of the pool is:

Comment: Thank you. The question is clear. Let's hope someone else offers another answer.

Comment: I've just found that last year someone on Stack Exchange tackled the question of oblique viewing. That person gave the same formula as I did (above)! So I think we can assume that it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer. I am still troubled on how did they come up with 2.1 meters??

Answer (score 0):

This equation:$\frac{Real\ depth}{Apparent \ depth}$=$\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}$

Is only valid for small angles.

Why?

Because in the derivation we approximate

sin($\theta)$~tan($\theta$)~$\frac{Real\ depth}{Apparent \ depth}$

Comment: Then what equation do we use when the angle isn't small?

Comment: How should I go about problems like this one?

Comment: Can you please link me with the sources you learned from or the ones that fully explain this problem and the tought process?

Comment: @JonNezbit https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296035/real-and-apparent-depth-not-looking-perpendicular-to-the-interface

Comment: I checked that one and I don't really understand it. I was looking for simpler and more understandable answer. Should i close my question?

Comment: @JonNezbit If u don't understand the derivation it's fine , at least you realized ur mistake. Closing / Not closing a question is upto u.